# Recursive string decompression

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, nested, compression

I'm trying to decompress strings that looks as follows:

Input: 4(ab)

Output: abababab

Input: 11ab

Output: aaaaaaaaaaab

Input: 2(3b3(ab))

Output: bbbabababbbbababab

The above examples all comes out correctly using the recursive method below but problems arise when I input something like:

Input: 4(ab)a

Expected output: ababababa

Input: 2(3b3(ab))a

Expected output:bbbabababbbbabababa

I realise the problems arise where in the return statement "return repeated". In its current state the recursion continues until it hits the end of the input string even after an ending parenthesis. Basically I don't know how to get it to break if reaching the ending parenthesis and then continue if there's anything left. In 2(3b3(ab))a it should return 2*(3b3(ab))+a, and now it returns 2*(3b3(ab))a. Any help is greatly appreciated, since I can't get my head around it.

```
public static String decompress(String compressedText) throws Exception
{
   //BASE CASE 
    if(compressedText.length() == 1)
    {
        if(compressedText.charAt(0) == ')')
        {
            System.out.println("1: " + compressedText);
            return "";
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("2: " + compressedText);
            return compressedText;
        }

    }
    //END BASECASE


    if(compressedText.charAt(0) == '(')
    {
        System.out.println("3: " + compressedText);
        return decompress(compressedText.substring(1));        
    }


    //IF DOUBLE DIGIT
    if(Character.isDigit(compressedText.charAt(0)) == true && Character.isDigit(compressedText.charAt(1)) == true)
    {
        if(compressedText.charAt(3) != '(')
        {
            System.out.println("4: " + compressedText);
            int i = Integer.parseInt(compressedText.substring(0,2));
            String repeated = new String(new char[i]).replace("\0", compressedText.substring(2,3));  
            return repeated + decompress(compressedText.substring(3));
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("5: " + compressedText);
            int i = Integer.parseInt(compressedText.substring(0,2));
            String repeated = new String(new char[i]).replace("\0", decompress(compressedText.substring(2)));
            return repeated;
        }

    }
    //END DOUBLE DIGIT



    //IF SINGLE DIGIT
    if (Character.isDigit(compressedText.charAt(0)) == true)
    {
        if(compressedText.charAt(1) !='(')
        {
            System.out.println("6: " + compressedText);
            int i = Integer.parseInt(compressedText.substring(0,1));
            String repeated = new String(new char[i]).replace("\0", compressedText.substring(1,2));  
            return repeated + decompress(compressedText.substring(2)); 
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("7: " + compressedText);
            int i = Integer.parseInt(compressedText.substring(0,1));
            String repeated = new String(new char[i]).replace("\0", decompress(compressedText.substring(1)));
            return repeated;
        }

    }
    //END SINGLE DIGIT

    //IF RIGHT PARENTHESIS
    if (compressedText.charAt(0) == ')')
    {
        if (compressedText.charAt(1) != ')')
        {
            System.out.println("8: " + compressedText);
            return "";
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("9: " + compressedText);
            return  decompress(compressedText.substring(1));

        }

    }
    //END 

        System.out.println("10: " + compressedText);
        return compressedText.charAt(0)+decompress(compressedText.substring(1));

}
```

Comment: Expected output for `2(3b3(ab))a` is `bbbabababbbbabababa`

Comment: Fun problem. You could use a recursive descent parser and a little BNF grammar. Then you could bang the code out in about 10 minutes.

Comment: ok, added JavaScript code example.

Answer (score 2):

Use a tuple for the return value of the recursion, which provides the index of the closing parenthesis in addition to the accumulated string:

```
index 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
str   2 ( 3 b 3 ( a b ) ) a

  f(0)

  => 2 * f(1)[0] add f(f(1)[1] + 1)  // f(1)[1] is the closing index 

    f(1) => 3 * b + 3 * f(5)[0] add f(f(5)[1] + 1)

    => f(5) returns (ab,8)

    f(1) => bbb + ababab add f(9) // str[9] is closing parenthesis

    => f(1) returns (bbbababab,9)

  => 2 * bbbababab add f(10)

  => bbbabababbbbabababa
```

JavaScript code:

```js
var example = '2(3b3(ab)2(cd3(fg)))ab2(gh2(xz))';

console.log(example);
console.log(decompress(example));

function decompress(s){

  // returns tuple [accumulator, index of closing parenthesis]
  function f(i){
  
    var accum = '',
        mult = '',
        curr = '';
      
    // accumulate all parenthetical groups in this level  
    while (i !== s.length){

      // closing parenthesis
      if (s[i] === ')'){
      
        // add the last decompression
        if (curr !== ''){
          accum += customReplicate(curr,mult);
        }
        
        // exit this call
        return [accum,i];
      }
          
      // character is a digit
      if (!isNaN(parseInt(s[i]))){
      
        // add previous decompression
        if (curr !== ''){
          accum += customReplicate(curr,mult);
          
          curr = '';
          mult = s[i];
          
        } else {
          mult += s[i];
        }
        
        i++;
        
      // character is a character
      } else if (s[i] !== '('){
      
        curr += s[i];
        i++;
        
      // parenthetical group 
      } else if (s[i] === '('){
      
        // recursive call
        [tempAccum,index] = f(i + 1);

        accum += customReplicate(tempAccum,mult);
        mult = '';
        i = index + 1;
      }
    }
    
    return accum + customReplicate(curr,mult);
  }
  
  // initialize the recursion
  return f(0);
}

function customReplicate(str,times){
  return new Array(times === '' ? 1 : parseInt(times))
                 .fill(str).join('');
}
```

Comment: I think I understand the logic of this but my java-knowledge is not sufficient to actually implement it. I tried adding a for-loop that "looked" ahead when  encountered with a digit followed by a parenthesis. Returning the compressed part contained within the parenthesis + whatever comes next.
Something like: 
return repeated(up until "))") + compressedtext(everything that comes after "))"). The problem with this is that when the input is the string used in in you code above this "))" appears twice.. 
So my question is how would this be implemented? And thanks for the answer!

Comment: @APL888 Thank you for your comment. I am not versed in Java; let me see if I can write a JavaScript version, which should not be too different, and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I've noticed is that you are "loosing" the last "a" when you return `""` after outputting `"8:"`. At that position the trailing chars should be handled as well, however you cannot simply return them there - neither directly nor by decompressing them -, because that would result in  `bbbabaabaababbbabaabaaba`.

Sadly, I didn't find a solution based on your code which returns the correct value (I guess there is some strange behavior in how you put the partly processed text into the recursion, but I'm not sure...).

However, I thought about how I would solve this compression thing and came up with two non-recursive solutions. Maybe they help you improve your solution. Side note: my solutions assume that the string is well-formed, that is it does not have any non-matching brackets etc.
(I used a repeat function that I've put at the end of my answer.)

The **first solution** uses a regular expression, which searches for the digits and the following part (either one char or a bracket-enclosed part which does not contain brackets itself). This way, the brackets and single-char decompressions are handled from the inside to the outside.

```
public static String decompressWithRegex(String s) {
    if ((s == null) || (s.length() == 0)) {
        return s;
    }
    // pattern for finding number with either bracket-enclosed, char-only part or single char
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)((?:[^\\d\\(\\)]{1})|(?:\\([^\\d\\(\\)]+\\)))");
    String tmp = s;
    Matcher m = p.matcher(tmp);
    // start searching
    while (m.find(0)) {
        // first capture group returns count
        int count = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        // second group is string to repeat (if it's bracket-enclosed, then remove brackets)
        String what = m.group(2).replace("(", "").replace(")", "");
        // build replacement part
        String replacePart = repeat(what, count);
        // replace it
        tmp = m.replaceFirst(replacePart);
        // reset matcher (source of matcher is now the new string)
        m.reset(tmp);
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

The **second solution** does not use regular expressions. Instead, it makes some assumptions about how the decompression can be handled:

- any number which is not followed by a bracket-enclosed part can be directly
  decompressed in-place, which is done first
- the bracket-enclosed part is handled by finding the first closing bracket
- then from there back to start the opening bracket is searched
- this gets you the part to repeat
- left of the opening bracket there should be a number which is then searched and parsed
- now that we have all the information, the replacement part is built and put in the right place
- then the next closing bracket is searched if there is any, and this is handled as above
- if there is no closing bracket, the string is decompressed

Code:

```
public static String decompressWithSearching(String s) {
    if ((s == null) || (s.length() == 0)) {
        return s;
    }
    // replace non-groups first
    for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // find digit that is not followed by bracket
        if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)) && s.charAt(i + 1) != '(') {
            // string to repeat is right behind the digit
            String part = s.substring(i + 1, i + 2);
            // find complete digit
            String countStr = "";
            int j = i;
            for ( ; j >= 0 && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(j)); j--) {
                countStr = s.charAt(j) + countStr;
            }
            int count = Integer.parseInt(countStr);
            // build replacement part
            String replacePart = repeat(part, count);
            // replace part
            s = s.substring(0, j + 1) + replacePart + s.substring(i + 2);
        }
    }

    // replace nested parts
    int closing;
    while ((closing = s.indexOf(')')) > -1) {
        // find matching opening bracket
        int opening = s.lastIndexOf('(', closing);
        // text between is to be repeated
        String what = s.substring(opening + 1,closing);
        // find complete digit
        String countStr = "";
        int numPartIndex = opening - 1;
        while (numPartIndex >= 0 && Character.isDigit(s.charAt(numPartIndex))) {
            countStr = s.charAt(numPartIndex) + countStr;
            numPartIndex--;
        }
        int count = Integer.parseInt(countStr);
        // build replacement part
        String replacePart = repeat(what, count);
        // replace part
        s = s.substring(0, numPartIndex + 1) + replacePart + s.substring(closing + 1);
    }

    return s;
}
```

Utility method for repeating a String:

```
public static String repeat(String what, int times) {
    if ((times <= 0) || (what == null) || (what.length() == 0)) {
        return "";
    }
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(times * what.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        buffer.append(what);
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: Nice. I really like the first example.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a Java question, but I usually write a small Ruby code to test an idea before implementing it in Java. If it interests anyone, here's my code :

```
def decompress(str)
  str.gsub!(/(\d+)([a-z])/i){$2*$1.to_i}       # Replace every subtring like "3b" and "11a".
  while str.include?('(') do
    str.sub!(/(\d+)\(([a-z]+)\)/){$2*$1.to_i}  # Replace the first inner group found
  end
  str
end

puts decompress("4(ab)")       == "abababab"
puts decompress("11ab")        == "aaaaaaaaaaab"
puts decompress("2(3b3(ab))")  == "bbbabababbbbababab"
puts decompress("4(ab)a")      == "ababababa"
puts decompress("2(3b3(ab))a") == "bbbabababbbbabababa"
#=> true, true, true, true, true
```

@jCoder wrote almost exactly the same thing in his first example, so no need to reinvent the wheel!